# select one record in certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to write a query that select one record when it meets certain condition.

table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvNHY.png)

With this table, I do not want to select a record with Contract_number 'MDE'  but if there is only one record with  the claimnumber, I'd like to select it even if the Contract_number is 'MDE'.

Comment: what platform are you using -- sql server, my sql, db2, oracle?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your attempt that didn’t work, if you made an attempt.

Comment: I am using MS SQL.

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Answer (score 1):

You can order the data and take on the first record

```
select top 1 *
from your_table
where claim_number = 17428835
order by case when contract_number <> 'MDE' then 1 else 2 end
```